# mail server with tls behind a cisco router

Tags: postfix

I have an email server with tls behind a cisco router. Tests for TLS connectins from inside prove that tls is configured just fine.

From a host on a local subnet:

```
zzzz@server:~# telnet mail.xxx.co.ug 25
Trying 192.168.1.20...
Connected to mail.xxx.co.ug.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.xxx.co.ug ESMTP Postfix
ehlo example.com
250-mail.xxx.co.ug
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 20240000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 NTLM CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=DIGEST-MD5 NTLM CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

From the router/internet host:
This is what I get from the router and when I telnet from an internet host to the mail server

```
`OME-GW#telnet mail.xxx.co.ug 25
Trying mail.xxx.co.ug (192.168.1.20, 25)... Open
220 mail.xxx.co.ug ESMTP Postfix
ehlo example.com
250-mail.xxx.co.ug
250-SIZE 20240000
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 NTLM CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
250 DSN`
```

Notice that there is no STARTTLS

Access Lists are configured to allow both pop3 and smtp through to the mail server, this is working as expected. Problem is that tls connections are not getting through to the mail server from the internet. Below is my external ACL from the Internet

```
Extended IP access list 102
    10 permit tcp any any eq pop3 (9768 matches)
    20 permit tcp any any eq smtp (66860 matches)
    30 permit tcp any any eq 1194 (279 matches)
    40 permit gre any any
    50 permit icmp any XXX.157.20.236 0.0.0.3 echo (7943 matches)
    60 permit icmp any XXX.157.20.236 0.0.0.3 echo-reply (75134 matches)
```

Comment: TLS connections over which port?

Comment: please check the updated question...